# SQL Syntax error Left/Inner/Right join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Im trying to connect / list the two different columns and it keeps showing up with a syntax error on the INNER join what is going on.

```
CREATE TABLE Artists
    (
      Name TEXT ,
      NumberOfMembers INTEGER ,
      CurrentlyActive TEXT
    );
CREATE TABLE BestSongsEver
    (
      Name TEXT ,
      SongTitle TEXT ,
      YearCreated INTEGER ,
      Ranking INTEGER ,
      genre TEXT ,
      TimesListenedTo INTEGER ,
      RatingScale INTEGER
    );
CREATE TABLE Languages
    (
      Ranking INTEGER ,
      Language TEXT
    );

INSERT  INTO Artists
VALUES  ( 'Nas', 1, 'Yes' );

INSERT  INTO BestSongsEver
VALUES  ( 'Nas', 'NY State of Mind', 1994, 7, 'Hip Hop', 27, 9.4 );


INNER JOIN BestSongsEver ON Artists.Name = BestSongsEver.Name;
```

Comment: what syntax error you are getting? post your complete query.

Comment: @HazarathChillara You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN BestSongsEver ON Artists.Name = BestSongsEver.Name' at line 1

Comment: It would sure be nice to see your query

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Artits A INNER JOIN BestSongEver BSE ON BSE.Name = A.Name
```

You can change the INNER JOIN into LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN and see the result.

See [this diagram](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) to understand joins better.